# How to delete last character in column values if greater than certain length in R?

Tags: r

I have data called `deseq.res`. It has a column called Gene. I want to delete values in this column if the value is of greater than 10 character length.

`deseq.res`

```
deseq.res<-structure(list(Gene = c("SS1G_0300902", "SS1G_024991", "SS1G_09248", 
"SS1G_09768"), sampleA = c("Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy"
), sampleB = c("Infected", "Infected", "Infected", "Infected"
)), .Names = c("Gene", "sampleA", "sampleB"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Result I want:

```
        Gene sampleA  sampleB
SS1G_03009 Healthy Infected
SS1G_02499 Healthy Infected
SS1G_09248 Healthy Infected
SS1G_09768 Healthy Infected
```

code I tried:

This is where I am having trouble, then I could simply use gsub or substring. I can do it with more elaborate way, but I wanted to use function to do this.

```
check.len<- function(x){if (length(deseq.res$Gene[x])>10) return (x)}
check.len(deseq.res$Gene)
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `substr` to get extract the first 10 character substring of the data

```
deseq.res$Gene <- substr(deseq.res$Gene, 1, 10)
```

Based on the OP's function, it is `nchar` instead of `length`

```
check.len <- function(x, n) ifelse(nchar(x) > n, substr(x, 1, n) , x)
check.len(deseq.res$Gene, n = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks! As always, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use library(dplyr) and mutate:

```
library(dplyr)
deseq.res <- deseq.res %>% mutate(Gene = substr(Gene,1,10))
```